# Where should I place redirection code?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React component that represents a page. Users should never reach the page unless they have some state. I wrote the following to have `react-router` redirect the user if state is missing:

```
class BoxScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if (Object.keys(this.props.boxState.current).length === 0) {
      browserHistory.push('/secured/find')
    }
```

I then get this message:

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Ok, so I'll move my redirection code to `componentWillMount`:

```
class BoxScreen extends Component {
   ...

   componentWillMount() {
    if (Object.keys(this.props.boxState.current).length === 0) {
      browserHistory.push('/secured/find')
    }
   }

   render() {
    // Don't want this executed or else I'll need to pollute it with null guards...
   }
}
```

However, the issue is that the above doesn't stop `render` from being called, which is definitely not desired. Where is the most appropriate spot to put this so I can short-circuit the component rendering and perform the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use react-router's `onEnter` prop to accomplish that:

```
function checkAuthenticated(nextState, replace) {
  if (!SOME_CONDITION) {
    replace('/secured/find')
  }
}

<Route ... onEnter={checkAuthenticated} />
```

But I believe you can't access the components props in this way. You'd have to keep track of the state in some other way. In case you're using Redux, I believe you could use [redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router) to get the store.

You can check the [Enter/leave hooks documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.2/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks)

Comment: I don't believe this works for React v16. I can't get this to work at all. Your documentation links are also dead.

Comment: @RyanBattistone At the time the stable version of React Router was v3.0.2, it's on v4.3.1 now. There has been some breaking changes.

I've updated the link for the version at the time I wrote the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use `react-router`'s `<Redirect/>` component inside render to achieve it, I am using v4 so I will provide you solution compatible to that.

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
class BoxScreen extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
       return this.props.condition ? 
                    <ActualComponent  /> : <Redirect to="/someGuardLink">;
    }
}
```

Replace `<ActualComponent />` with your components JSX, and yah, this should work. Your component will still mount and render but after that it is going to redirect you to some other link without you getting to notice any effect of it. This is the official way of doing it.

Comment: Also, I would suggest not to interrupt constructor-to-render flow of a component, either use Lucas's approach to not even enter the component lifecycle at all, or once you enter it, you should not try to interrupt it. A better way could be that you let the component render with a null guard, and do `this.history.push('/someGuardLink')` in `componentDidMount()` checking `this.props`.

Comment: Your solution is much more elegant and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what smishr4 had to say:

1. Have a default state for your object in the reducer. For example, my initial state for an ID is:

```js
ID: -1
```

2. Be sure that you've mapped your object from state to props.

```js
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        ID: state.ID,       
    }
}
```

3. On anything that extends from React.Component, write an if condition within the componentWillMount() function - so that this happens before page load. This particular function will route me back to the homepage, if the .ID field is undefined (which is always initially true), and after it is set to its initial state in the reducer (-1).

```js
    componentWillMount() {
        {
            if (this.props.ID != -1 && this.props.ID != undefined) {
                this.props.loadYourDataFromAPIGivenID(this.props.ID);
            }
            else {
                this.props.history.push('/');
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way? Probably. You might be able to do the blocking within the router directly, but this is a good work around.

**You can also use this.state directly**, but this.props is a bit safer to use.